# Get value outside function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is what i'm trying to do:

```
$.getJSON( "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+latitude+"&lon="+longitude", function(data) { 
fh = data;
});
```

I'm trying to do a

```
console.log(fh);
```

outside **$.getJSON**

Is it possible to get the **fh** var outside this function ?
I'm trying this and shows me an error at the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: fh is not defined

Comment: Why are you trying to access the data outside the function in the first place? What does "outside this function" even mean? It probably won't work as you expect. Please read [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/218196) and [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/218196), two of the top 10 most frequently asked JavaScript questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm just trying to learn something man... take it easy.

Comment: And I am just trying to help. If you explain why and where you need to access the data "outside the function", we can provide you a proper solution. You should never have to use a global variable to share the data like this. Usually you pass the response to another function, e.g. `function outside(fh) { console.log(fh); } $.getJSON(..., function(data) { outside(data); });`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create `fh` as a global variable which will then allow it be updated within the `getJSON` method and accessed outside of the method.

It will be equal to `undefined` until a response has been received from  the getJSON request to the server due.

For this reason, and to see it working you should use `setTimeout`. In practice you should use `promises`, but that may be outside the scope of the question. As long as the server has responded within 2 seconds the value of `fh` will be set to the data returned from the server.

The code below demonstrates this.

```js
var fh;

$.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weatherlat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude, function(data) { 
    fh = data;
});

setTimeout(function(){
  console.log(fh)
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

this non blocking code so that you must wait call back execution

```
$.getJSON( "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+latitude+"&lon="+longitude", function(data) { 

fh = data;
console.log(fh);

});
```

Comment: While it is certainly possible to do that, `console.log(fh)` will log `null`. Please mention that and explain what the OP should do instead.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to use fh outside for something in your logic

you can work around with setInterval function

```
var fh=null;
$.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weatherlat="+latitude+"&lon="+longitude", function(data) {
    fh = data;
});

var interval=setInterval(function(){
        if(fh!=null){
           console.log(fh)
           clearInterval(interval)
        }
},500)
```

Comment: While this works, its unnecessarily complex. It would make a lot more sense to pass `data` to a function after it was received.

Answer (score 0):

In Side function we need to set the value

```
localStorage.setItem('fhname',fh);
```

Outside function we need to get the value

```
localStorage.getItem('fhname');
```